# Dynamic UITabBarController, Remotely Changing TabBarItems using JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Working on an app that allows administrators to change features of the app from the cloud.

At `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I'm pulling data from the cloud.. For example the admin might change the color of a certain element on the website, which then updates the exported JSON code, which the app would then pull to change the UITabBarController tintColor

At `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` my app pulls JSON data, i've parsed out the data and stored it in public variables. Within my UITabBarController.swift file's viewDidLoad method I dynamically add all the enabled ViewControllers to the TabBarController, I also set the `tabBar.barTintColor` this way:

```
 if tabBarColor (this is one of the public variables that stores JSON data) == "Blue" {
        println(tabBarColor)
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    else {
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        println(tabBarColor)
    }
```

Using the logs, and breakpoints I know for certain that when this if statement is called, tabBarColor does == "Blue"

However, the tabBar.barTintColor equals whatever is in the else statement, behaving as though tabBarColor doesn't equal blue, even though I know it does!
*Note: this behaves even if the viewDidLoad method runs the JSON code and uses a local variable to store the JSON data.*

Whats interesting is that after about 30 seconds, the tabBar.barTintColor switches!

What could be causing this? Any ideas on a fix/better way to accomplish what I'm trying?

Comment: Instead of comparing string, have you tried using NSString function isEqualToString?

Comment: I just tried using isEqualToString. It behaved as before but I noticed something very strange. If I set breakpoints for the viewDidLoad method, and stepped through it until viewDidLoad method completed, it set the correct color

Comment: this method is inside the viedDidLoad method right?